# Geometric proof for perpendicular lines

Tags: geometry

Could you please explain to me how I would provide a geometric proof for the below problem.

Let $ABCD$ be a square. Suppose that points $K$ and $L$ are chosen on the sides $AB$ and $BC$ respectively so that $KB=LC$. It is known that $AL$ and $CK$ meet at point $P$. Provide a proof that shows that $DP$ and $KL$ are perpendicular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add lines $DK$ and $DL$ to your diagram.

Triangles $KBC$ and $LCD$ are congruent, so it follows that $CK \perp DL$ (because $\angle LDC = \angle KCB$ ).

Similarly, triangles $DAK$ and $ABL$ are also congruent, so $AL \perp DK$.

Then point P is orthocenter of triangle $DKL$ and because heights in triangle are concurrent (meeting in one point) $DP \perp KL$.

Comment: this is a nice argument.

Comment: What is orthocenter?

Comment: Orthocenter is a point where 3 heights (altitudes) of a triangle meet.

Comment: Why is CK perpendicular to DL?

Comment: Let point $E$ be intersection of lines $CK$ and $DL$. Since triangles $KBC$ and $LCD$ are congruent then $\angle LDC = \angle KCB= \alpha$ .Then  $\angle DEC=180 - \angle LCD - \angle DCE =180-\alpha - 90+\alpha =90 $because $\angle DCE = 90 - \alpha$

Answer (score 0):

Construction looks something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyBa9.jpg

[image]

I'll try to do this by finding the slope of KL and DP and show they are always reciprocals of each other. This took an hour dont reccomend using this method.

Let square $ABCD$ be represented by a square with sides $S$, and let points  lie as follows

$$A (0,S)\quad B (S,S)\quad C (S,0)\quad D (0,0)$$

$|KB| = |LC|$ I'll call this distance $d$

Slope between $K$ and $L = \dfrac {\text{rise}}{\text{run}} = \dfrac {-(S-d)}{d}$

$P$ is defined by the intersection between $KC$ and $AL$

Line $KC$: $$y(d,x,S)  =S\frac{-(S-x)}{d}$$

Line $AL$: $$y(d,x,S)  =S + \frac{-x(S - d)}{S}$$

Point P: $$P = \left(\frac{S^2 (-d + S)}{d^2 - d S + S^2}, S -\frac{d S (-d + S)}{-d^2 + d S + S^2}\right)$$

Slope DP: $$DP = \frac{S -\dfrac{d S (-d + S)}{-d^2 + d S + S^2}}{\dfrac{S^2 (-d + S)}{d^2 - d S + S^2}}=\frac{d}{-d+S}$$

And finally $\dfrac{\dfrac{d}{-d+S}}{\dfrac {-(S-d)}{d}} = -1$, the lines are perpendicular.

Because the product of the slopes of $DP$ and $KL$ is $-1$, the lines are perpendicular.

Answer (score 0):

Let $AL=(j,(1-a)j)$ (a parametrized line, where $j$ is the parameter and $a$ is the distance $|KB|$. Represent $CK=(1-ka,1-k)$. To find $P$ we find the point of intersection, i.e.:

$j=1-ka$

$(1-a)j=1-k$

So $(1-a)=\dfrac{1-k}{1-ka}$

Expanding we get : $1-ka-a+ka^2=1-k$, cancel the $1$'s to get $-ka-a+ka^2=-k$ and re-arrange : $k+ka+ka^2=a$, so $k=\dfrac{a}{1+a+a^2}$.

Now $j=1-ka=1-\dfrac{a^2}{1+a+a^2}=\dfrac{1+a}{1+a+a^2}$, and so $j$ and $k$ have the same ratio as points similar to $K$ and $L$ around $D$.